# Knight promotion percentages

Tags: statistics, knights, pawn-promotion, check

Knight promotion is the second most common promotion. Most of the time it is to give an otherwise undeliverable check. But it doesn’t always come with check. Statistically speaking, what percentage of knight promotions come with check and percentage doesn’t come with check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ChessBase allows you to search for positions with promotions to each piece, with or without check. In the Mega 2019 database, there are 8,266,473 games.

In those games, there are 486,622 promotions to queen; 7,223 promotions to knight; 1,486 promotions to bishop; and 9,606 promotions to rook. Of the 7,223 promotions to knight, 5,733 came with check, or 79.3%. Bonus: Of the 5,733 knight promotions with check, 106 were mate on the move.

Of course, Mega does not have every game, but this can give you a pretty close idea.

Comment: Small comment: For sound stats and a scientific article  :-), you also would have to check (no pun intended) each and any promotion whether it was a "nonsense" promotion. If it was nonsense, maybe the player was in time trouble and quickly hammered a rook on the board (not anyone knows you may stop the clock to order a second queen from the referee).

Comment: Just a small note, some games where a pawn that's about to (most likely) promote to a queen were resigned before a promotion happened, so maybe there were some more games where if it were to be played on, more promotions to either piece would've happened.

Comment: wow. more promotions to rook than knight. insane.