# What are the percentage rates for each promotion type?

Tags: database, statistics, pawn-promotion

I could not find the database which has this, but I would like to know what percentage of promoted pawns ends up being a queen, rook, bishop, or knight

Comment: [This answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/26799/21604) seems to indirectly tell you what you want to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the percentages for each promotion type according to different sources:

```
|Promotion type  | ChessBase | TWIC | ICCF |
--------------------------------------------
| Queen          |      96.9 | 97.3 | 96.1 |
| Rook           |       1.1 |  1.1 |  1.7 |
| Knight         |       1.8 |  1.3 |  1.7 |
| Bishop         |       0.2 |  0.3 |  0.5 |
```

Details:

- ChessBase: Percentages from 2006 ChessBase, with 3.2 million games, obtained from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_(chess)).
- TWIC: Percentages calculated using my own script from 1.4 million games published in [The Week In Chess](https://theweekinchess.com/twic), issues 920 (Jun. 25th, 2012) to 1358 (Nov. 16th, 2020).
- ICCF: Percentages calculated using my own script from 0.8 million games made available by the [International Correspondence Chess Federation](https://www.iccf.com/), from the 1970s to 2018.

Comment: @timosenko1 If you think I have answered your question sufficiently well, feel free to accept it.

Comment: wow 1.1% for rook. only 0.7% behind knight. insane.